# How to fix ios7 geofencing inaccuracy while in background

Tags: ios7, geofencing

My client would like their customers to get a local notification when within 100 meters of a set list of locations in the area. However, there seems to be a problem where the notifications are being generated when the users are up to 5 miles outside of the defined regions. I have double checked the code and cannot seem to find anything wrong. I have read that geofencing while in the background can be inaccurate which seems to be exactly what I am experiencing. Has anyone dealt with this? One method I have considered is double checking the users actual location in the didEnterRegion method, but I am not sure how accurate that will be if the application is technically in the background, and assumed I would probably get the same coordinates that were inaccurate to begin with. Any thoughts?